# Bootstrap: how to clear images in a gallery?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

first a link to the site through github http://torgian.github.io/website-dev/gallery.html

Apologies for any spelling mistakes, been working on this for several hours today.

This is directly to the gallery.

UPDATE#2
  Further updated code. HUGE thanks to msfoster for setting me on the right path. Amazing how simple the fix was... I just didn't know what it was! Ahahaha xD

*slams down sake* I feel like I want to run up a mountain now... but it's 10pm here in Japan, so I'll wait till tomorrow.

Code block coming up with fixes.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 image-wrapper"> <a href="img/nasarow-fo-to1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
         <img src="img/nasarow-fo-to1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-height">
      </a></div>
```

The above was a list of 7 image divs, separated into two rows. That was my first problem. So I removed the second row, but still had a problem with images not staying in one uniform row.

So I next put in this CSS:

```
.image-wrapper {
height: 300px;
width: auto;}
```

It took some experimenting to get the height and width right, but found that if I let the width to AUTO and kept the height at a fixed rate, the images were still responsive to viewport size and stayed in the same uniform row.

Gods that was hard.

I'm not sure if this is a permanent fix or not, but I will be revisiting it in the future when I add more galleries.

---

I'm using bootstrap to create a gallery with the grid system. Unfortunately, I've been trying to get things to line up correctly for the past few days. I cant quite seem to get clearfix to work correctly, I don't know if I'm putting the code into the wrong spot into the html or not.

Also tried nth-child code, but I'm stuck on that as well.

I'll continue to research as I wait for answers, but could definitely use some help.

Suggestions?

In CSS I have the height limited to 300px. You can see that some of the pictures are higher than others, and I think this is what's causing the break, but just cant figure out how to keep the pictures from dropping down to the next row instead of having the 2 or 3 pictures I need in each row.

---

Background: student of HTML and CSS right now. Updating my site as I go through Treehouse courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it breaks is the fact that you create a new `row` for every third image.

```
# # #
```

will break to

```
# #
#
```

And then the next image is within a new row again:

```
# #
#
#
```

Put all images inside one row and they will breake according to the `col-x-y` you set for each image.

Comment: OK, updated the page with your suggestion. I remember having it this way originally, but if you take a look, once the viewport gets larger, the "shorter" images wrap to the right of the "taller" images.

Comment: Just set a height for `.image-wrapper`

Comment: @Nathan did you solve it? I realized that you have to have a dynamic height. If not, have a look at http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-thumbnail-gallery/

Comment: just saw your comment. I will update image wrapper and tool around with the code a bit. See if I cant fix it. Thanks for your help so far, I'll update soon.

Comment: Ah.. haha... BWAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!

I finally got it. God damn. 

I'm going to have a glass of sake now. 

msfoster, thanks a LOT for setting me on the right path.

Comment: Awesome. Enjoy the glass of Sake.